# Javascript : Syntax error on token "delete", StringLiteral?

Tags: javascript, eclipse

```
    var TestFunction = function () {

        return {
           delete: function() { // line 1
                // do something
            }
        };
    }
```

Getting below error on line 1 in eclipse

```
    Syntax error on token "delete", StringLiteral
```

As i changed "delete" to "delete1" , error goes away . Is delete a reserved keyword ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) is a reserved keyword, used to remove a property in an object, so that it is not iterable anymore. Thus, given:

```
var a = { b: 5 };
delete a.b;
console.log(a);
// logs {}
```

It can be also used to remove "global variables" that are actually properties of the global object too, that is:

```
delete a;
// is in browsers equal to
delete window.a;
```

Notice that you can use `delete` as a property name too, however you need to always quote it:

```
var obj = {
    'delete': function() { // line 1
        // do something
    }
};
obj['delete']();
```