# Three.js - how to resolve syntax error on delete in Eclipse

Tags: javascript, eclipse, three.js

The Javascript Library Three.js [uses the delete keyword](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/7298) as an object property. This is valid as of ECMAScript 5, but [Eclipse only has support for ECMA 3](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/issues/70). [According to the Mozilla reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Reserved_word_usage), "Reserved words actually only apply to Identifiers," not properties. Also I tried disabling the JS validation in Eclipse but it's still giving me errors. Is there some way to update the ECMA validation? Or to turn off JS validation? I tried everything but nothing seems to work.

See also: [Javascript : Syntax error on token "delete", StringLiteral?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24444581/javascript-syntax-error-on-token-delete-stringliteral) But the answer is wrong, because the syntax is technically valid.

Comment: Ouch. Life's too short for an editor that hasn't yet reached 2009. I guess switching isn't an option?

Comment: If you have an alternative that has Maven, XSD, and Git support, also good code intelligence. And free (yes, I know IntelliJ is amazing, but also expensive).

Comment: You could swap-out the editor in Eclipse to VIM or Sublime etc. See the docs.

Comment: I just bought IntelliJ. I'm surprised at this solution but it's true - Eclipse is constantly behind and full of bugs that never get fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer I'm the autor of tern.java.

At first, I suggest you that you install [tern.java](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java) which gives a [support for Three.js](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/Tern-&-Threejs-support)

To fix your problem with validation:

- with the released Eclipse Mars, you must remove the JSDT nature, by editing your `.project` and removing the line   `<nature>org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.jsNature</nature>`
- in the next version of Eclipse, Eclipse JSDT is improving it and you will able to disable it See https://eclipse.org/projects/project-plan.php?projectid=webtools.jsdt

After if you wish to benefit with Validation, you can use [JSHint support with tern.java](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/Tern-Linter-JSHint).