# ajax type: 'DELETE' is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js

In the console I get "internal server error (500)".

In my nodeJS console I get "ReferenceError: request is not defined"

Here is the code I used:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.delete-article').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $target = $(e.target);
    const id = $target.attr('data-id');
    $.ajax({
      type:'DELETE',
      url:'/article/'+id,
      success: function(response){
        alert('Deleting Article')
        window.location.href = '/';
      },
      error: function(err){
        console.log('error for some reason: '+err);
      }
    })
  })
});
```

my JavaScript:

```
app.delete('/article/:id', function(req, res){
  let query = {_id:request.params.id};
  Article.remove(query, function(err){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    }
    res.send('Success');
  });
})
```

I just can't seem to figure out what I did wrong, all seems fine to me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript : Syntax error on token "delete", StringLiteral?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24444581/javascript-syntax-error-on-token-delete-stringliteral)

Comment: i mean... maybe it's because `request` is not defined. just guessing here, that's definitely a possibility though.

Answer (score 0):

Its a typo as you are using `req` not `request` so change this `let query = {_id:request.params.id};` to `let query = {_id:req.params.id};`

```
app.delete('/article/:id', function(req, res){
  let query = {_id:req.params.id};
  Article.remove(query, function(err){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    }
    res.send('Success');
  });
})
```

Comment: @KillianC that is why we have caffeine

Comment: We have a close reason for typo questions because they aren't useful to future visitors. we don't need to answer these.

Comment: @KevinB I'll take care next time if i see any typo questions.. thanks for pointing it.